# Why some end and start tags in html are optional?

Tags: html

The [optgroup](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-optgroup-element) end tag and [colgroup](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-colgroup-element) start tag is optional as per html5 live standard.

Can someone please enlighten, if there is any specific purpose/benefit behind keeping some start and end tags optional as per w3c?

Reference :  Section 2.4 of www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/

I have searched so/google but couldn't find any satisfactory explanation.
Please provide link to pages, if you know, which could sum up elements start and end tag omission.

Comment: Generally speaking it's mostly for the author's convenience (and because it is not XML). There are some situations where you can safely omit the start and/or end tags for an element and be guaranteed a specific behavior, so they give you the freedom to do so. For example, since p elements can never contain other p elements, there is no reason you shouldn't be able to just write `<p>paragraph 1<p>paragraph 2` etc. There are plenty of cases where omitting otherwise optional tags can change the meaning of a fragment, though, so it's not all roses.

Comment: Thank you, your example makes sense. so will have to learn these omission as per w3c's , there's no one size fits all.